# SQL Query : Sum(@variable)

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

Could someone tell me please why there is a difference between the two last column i get when i run this simple query?

In this example, the last column is the same as the third shifted back one position with a first row which contains *NULL*.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(PRICE), 
  @sum := SUM(PRICE) , 
  ln(SUM(PRICE)), 
  ln(@sum) 
FROM 
  TABLE 
group by ISIN
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because the `@sum` variable is assigned the value after the values from each group are created. In the last column the current value of `@sum` is used to create the value, so that will be what was assigned from the previous group.

Comment: So, what would be the solution please?

Comment: Use the third expression . . . repeat the expression rather than use the variable.